# Debugging Azure IoT Edge modules using Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-iot-edge

I can't get local debug of IoT Edge modules working on VS Code, but part of the problem could be that I don't understand what I'm doing in the steps.

I'm following the Microsoft guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-vs-code-develop-module?view=iotedge-2018-06#set-up-iot-edge-simulator-for-single-module-app). Can anyone explain to me when I run the command "Azure IoT Edge: Start IoT Edge Hub Simulator for Single Module" in VS Code, why do I need to pass an "input name"? Why doesn the simulator need to know this. I've got multiple input commands on my edge module and the fact I need to pass it is making me question what the simulator actually does. I want to be able to debug multiple inputs.

Also on the same documentation, I can't see how it defines which module I want to run in the simulator. Am I missing something or is the process confusing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you **Start the IoT Edge Hub Simulator for a Single Module**, you spawn two Docker containers. One is the edgeHub and the other is a testing utility. The testing utility acts as a server that you can send HTTP requests to, the requests specify the input name and the data. You can use this to send messages to various inputs on your module. Just looking at that, I understand why it is confusing to supply the input name to the simulator. But when you inspect the edgeHub container, you'll see the following environment values being passed:

```
"routes__output=FROM /messages/modules/target/outputs/* INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/input/inputs/print\")",
"routes__r1=FROM /messages/modules/input/outputs/input2 INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/target/inputs/input2\")",
"routes__r2=FROM /messages/modules/input/outputs/foo INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/target/inputs/foo\")",
"routes__r3=FROM /messages/modules/input/outputs/input1 INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/target/inputs/input1\")"
```

Just like on a real device, you need routes to talk to your module. The edgeHub container registers these routes with the values you supplied during the starting of the simulator. That input can be a comma-separated list. So if you are using more inputs, feel free to supply them when you start the simulator. Under the covers, that command runs:

```sh
iotedgehubdev start -i "input1,input2,foo"
```

Note: when I was testing this with the latest VS Code Extension, the first time I ran it, the textbox contained: "input1,input2".